# How to get the last inserted ID from MSSQL server?

Tags: php, sql-server

First off, this question has been asked before but my code style is a bit different than those in the previous questions.

I have MSSQL server and I use PHP to insert into my database.

This works.

I just need to get the last inserted ID after it has been inserted.

So this is my code:

```
    $email=str_replace("'","''", $_POST['email']);
    $password=str_replace("'","''", $_POST['password']);

    $query="INSERT INTO Profiles(";
    $query=$query."VP_Email,";
    $query=$query."VP_Password";
    $query=$query.") VALUES (?,?) SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() AS ins_id";   

    $stmt = sqlsrv_prepare($conn, $query, array(&$email, &$password));
    $result = sqlsrv_execute($stmt); 

    if (!$result) {
        echo "error: Insert Error";
        exit;
    } else {
        sqlsrv_next_result($stmt);
        sqlsrv_fetch($stmt);
        $Profileid = sqlsrv_get_field($stmt,0);     

    }

  echo $Profileid;
```

When i run my code, the data gets inserted into the database but the `$Profileid` is always empty!

Could someone please advice on this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You shouldn't be storing passwords in plain text. Apart from that the SQL looks OK if that table does actually have an `IDENTITY` column - not sure about the PHP part

Comment: @MartinSmith, the SQL part must be OK if the INSERT works fine.

Comment: @MartinSmith also regarding the password being in plain text, this is not my code. I haven't written it. also, its not a live project. its just an internal test that a friend of mine is working on.

Comment: have you verified the table does definitely have an IDENTITY column and isnt using sequences instead?

Comment: @MartinSmith, Yes. just double checked the database and there is deffinetly a column called VP_id which holds all the IDs.

Comment: looking at the column name and contents is not sufficient. you need to check how they are generated. Is it using an IDENTITY or a sequence?

Comment: `sqlsrv_next_result` is used to move to the next result set. Your `insert` doesn't return anything, so are you sure this is required?